# Write data from JSON to Excel using VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I try to extract JSON data from an API to Excel table using VBA.
I have installed VBA-JSON and turned on `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

The json request delivers:

```json
[
  {
    "Itemcode": "6FSTGWD40",
    "DeliveryTimeInDays": 999,
    "PalletQuantity": 12,
    "Description": "Fiberstone",
    "ItemDescription_NL": "Fiberstone",
    "ItemStatus": "E",
    "SalesPackage_NL": "Stuks   ",
    "SalesPackage_DE": "Stück",
    "SalesPackage_EN": "Unit",
    "SalesPackage_FR": "Pièce",
    "Salesprice": 132,
    "MainGroupCode": "200",
    "MainGroupDescription_NL": "Hardware",
    "MainGroupDescription_DE": "Hardware",
    "MainGroupDescription_EN": "Hardware",
    "MainGroupDescription_FR": "Hardware",
    "ProductGroupCode": "300",
    "ProductGroupDescription_NL": "Plantenbakken",
    "ProductGroupDescription_DE": "Gefässe",
    "ProductGroupDescription_EN": "Planters",
    "ProductGroupDescription_FR": "Bacs",
    "GroupDescription": "FSTC",
    "GroupDescription_NL": "Pottery Pots Fiberstone",
    "GroupDescription_DE": "Pottery Pots Fiberstone",
    "GroupDescription_EN": "Pottery Pots Fiberstone",
    "GroupDescription_FR": "Pottery Pots Fiberstone",
    "MaterialGroupCode": "500",
    "MaterialGroupDescription_NL": "Composiet",
    "MaterialGroupDescription_DE": "Verbundwerkstoff",
    "MaterialGroupDescription_EN": "Composite",
    "MaterialGroupDescription_FR": "Matériau composite",
    "ItemDescription_EN": "Fiberstone",
    "ItemDescription_DE": "Fiberstone",
    "ItemDescription_FR": "Fiberstone",
    "GTINCode": "8717775668411",
    "IsStockItem": true,
    "Warehouse": "A",
    "ItemVariety_NL": "Dice XL Glossy White",
    "ItemVariety_DE": "Dice XL Glossy White",
    "ItemVariety_EN": "Dice XL Glossy White",
    "ItemVariety_FR": "Dice XL Glossy White",
    "PotSize": null,
    "ItemPictureName": "6FSTGWD40.png",
    "ItemPictureSysmodified": "2019-03-04T11:51:24",
    "Content_Ltr": null,
    "PlantPassportCode": null,
    "Diameter": 46,
    "Length": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 60,
    "Depth": 59,
    "Opening": 36,
    "IsOffer": false,
    "ShowOnWebsite": false,
    "Sysmodified": "2021-07-13T07:38:08.853",
    "SalesOrderSize": 1,
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Code": "Brand",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Pottery Pots",
            "Description_DE": "Pottery Pots",
            "Description_EN": "Pottery Pots",
            "Description_FR": "Pottery Pots"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Collection",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Essential",
            "Description_DE": "Essential",
            "Description_EN": "Essential",
            "Description_FR": "Essential"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "ColourPlanter",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Wit",
            "Description_DE": "Weiß",
            "Description_EN": "White",
            "Description_FR": "Blanche"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Finish",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Hoogglans",
            "Description_DE": "Hochglanz",
            "Description_EN": "High gloss",
            "Description_FR": "Brillant"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Location",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Buiten",
            "Description_DE": "Draußen",
            "Description_EN": "Outdoor",
            "Description_FR": "Extérieur"
          },
          {
            "Description_NL": "Binnen",
            "Description_DE": "Innen",
            "Description_EN": "Indoor",
            "Description_FR": "Intérieur"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Material",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Fiberstone",
            "Description_DE": "Fiberstone",
            "Description_EN": "Fiberstone",
            "Description_FR": "Fiberstone"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "MaterialProperties",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Handgemaakt",
            "Description_DE": "Handgefertigt",
            "Description_EN": "Handmade",
            "Description_FR": "Fait à la main"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Serie",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Fiberstone",
            "Description_DE": "Fiberstone",
            "Description_EN": "Fiberstone",
            "Description_FR": "Fiberstone"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Shape",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Cylinder",
            "Description_DE": "Cylinder",
            "Description_EN": "Cylinder",
            "Description_FR": "Cylinder"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "Structure",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Egaal",
            "Description_DE": "Glatt",
            "Description_EN": "Smooth",
            "Description_FR": "Lisse"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "Itemcode": "8EE425140",
    "DeliveryTimeInDays": 2,
    "PalletQuantity": 288,
    "Description": "Begonia maculata",
    "ItemDescription_NL": "Begonia maculata",
    "ItemStatus": "A",
    "SalesPackage_NL": "Stuks   ",
    "SalesPackage_DE": "Stück",
    "SalesPackage_EN": "Unit",
    "SalesPackage_FR": "Pièce",
    "Salesprice": 8.45,
    "MainGroupCode": "200",
    "MainGroupDescription_NL": "Hardware",
    "MainGroupDescription_DE": "Hardware",
    "MainGroupDescription_EN": "Hardware",
    "MainGroupDescription_FR": "Hardware",
    "ProductGroupCode": "600",
    "ProductGroupDescription_NL": "Artificial ",
    "ProductGroupDescription_DE": "Artificial ",
    "ProductGroupDescription_EN": "Artificial ",
    "ProductGroupDescription_FR": "Artificielle",
    "GroupDescription": "KUC",
    "GroupDescription_NL": "Artificial decoration",
    "GroupDescription_DE": "Artificial Dekoration",
    "GroupDescription_EN": "Artificial decoration",
    "GroupDescription_FR": "Décoration artificielles",
    "MaterialGroupCode": null,
    "MaterialGroupDescription_NL": null,
    "MaterialGroupDescription_DE": null,
    "MaterialGroupDescription_EN": null,
    "MaterialGroupDescription_FR": null,
    "ItemDescription_EN": "Begonia maculata",
    "ItemDescription_DE": "Begonia maculata",
    "ItemDescription_FR": "Begonia maculata",
    "GTINCode": "8714344320619",
    "IsStockItem": true,
    "Warehouse": "A",
    "ItemVariety_NL": "Tak",
    "ItemVariety_DE": "Zweig",
    "ItemVariety_EN": "Branch",
    "ItemVariety_FR": "Branche",
    "PotSize": "0",
    "ItemPictureName": "8EE425140.png",
    "ItemPictureSysmodified": "2020-02-11T08:57:17",
    "Content_Ltr": null,
    "PlantPassportCode": null,
    "Diameter": 0,
    "Length": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 120,
    "Depth": 0,
    "Opening": 0,
    "IsOffer": false,
    "ShowOnWebsite": true,
    "Sysmodified": "2021-07-06T07:38:14.623",
    "SalesOrderSize": 1,
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Code": "ArtificialGroup",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Overig",
            "Description_DE": "Andere",
            "Description_EN": "Other",
            "Description_FR": "Autres"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "ArtificialType",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Tak",
            "Description_DE": "Ast",
            "Description_EN": "Branch",
            "Description_FR": "Branche"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Code": "ArtificialVariety",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Planten",
            "Description_DE": "Pflanzen",
            "Description_EN": "plants-artificial",
            "Description_FR": "Plantes"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

With the following code I can write the items `Itemcode`, `DeliveryTimeInDays`, `PalletQuantity` and so on in specific Excel cells.

I don't get it to work to write the "Tags" with "Code" and "Values" in Excel cells.

```vb
Sub test_json()
' dieses makro ist der startpunkt: einholen von aid, ean etc. dieses makro ruft eine liste aller artikel mit status ab.
Worksheets("test").Range("a1:zz100000").ClearContents
Dim ws As Worksheet, jsonObject As Object, jsonText As String, i As Long, http As Object
    i = 3
    'requesturl = "https://customerapi_dev.nieuwkoop-europe.com/items?sysmodified=2000-01-01"
     requesturl = "https://customerapi_dev.nieuwkoop-europe.com/items?sysmodified=2021-02-11&itemCode=6PPNLBO80"
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        http.Open "GET", requesturl, False
        http.send
        
        Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Itemcode"
Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 2).Value = "DeliveryTimeInDays"
Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 3).Value = "PalletQuantity"

For Each Item In jsonObject
Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("Itemcode")
Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("DeliveryTimeInDays")
Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("PalletQuantity")

i = i + 1
Next Item
    
End Sub
```

I tried as loop code like the following but I always get an error.

```vb
For Each Item In jsonObject ("Tags")("Code")("Values")
Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("Description_NL")
Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("Description_DE")
Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("Description_FR")

i = i + 1
Next Item
```

How can I write the "Tags" data (for instance "Code" and values like `Description_NL`) from JSON file in the Excel cells too?

Answer (score 1):

Values is an array (parsed into a collection) so you want `tag("Values")(n)`

```vb
 Dim item, tag, n as Long
    For Each item In jsonObject
        For Each tag In item("Tags")
            For n = 1 to tag("Values").Count
                Debug.Print tag("Values")(n)("Description_NL")
            Next
        Next
    Next item
```

Alternatively iterate the objects

```vb
    Dim item, tag, val
    For Each item In jsonObject
        For Each tag In item("Tags")
            For Each val In tag("Values")
                Debug.Print item("Itemcode"), tag("Code"), val("Description_NL")
            Next
        Next
    Next item
```

Comment: Some but not all items have more than 1 element in Values array:  {
        "Code": "Location",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Description_NL": "Buiten",
            "Description_DE": "Draußen",
            "Description_EN": "Outdoor",
            "Description_FR": "Extérieur"
          },
          {
            "Description_NL": "Binnen",
            "Description_DE": "Innen",
            "Description_EN": "Indoor",
            "Description_FR": "Intérieur"
          } what can I do in these cases? writing tag("Values")(2)("Description_NL") does not work.

Comment: @phill Sorry missed Location, see update (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Following the first comment from CDP1802, I coded another `for each` loop and it works fine:

```
Sub getactivearticleswithstatus()

Dim ws As Worksheet, jsonObject As Object, jsonText As String, i As Long, http As Object
Dim item, tag, eigenschaft
Dim j, m


i = 3
   requesturl="..."
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        http.Open "GET", requesturl, False
        http.send
        
        Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)


For Each item In jsonObject
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 1).value = item("Itemcode")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 2).value = item("DeliveryTimeInDays")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 3).value = item("PalletQuantity")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 4).value = item("Description")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 5).value = item("ItemDescription_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 6).value = item("ItemStatus")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 7).value = item("SalesPackage_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 8).value = item("SalesPackage_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 9).value = item("SalesPackage_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 10).value = item("SalesPackage_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 11).value = item("Salesprice")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 12).value = item("MainGroupCode")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 13).value = item("MainGroupDescription_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 14).value = item("MainGroupDescription_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 15).value = item("MainGroupDescription_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 16).value = item("MainGroupDescription_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 17).value = item("ProductGroupCode")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 18).value = item("ProductGroupDescription_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 19).value = item("ProductGroupDescription_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 20).value = item("ProductGroupDescription_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 21).value = item("ProductGroupDescription_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 22).value = item("GroupDescription")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 23).value = item("GroupDescription_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 24).value = item("GroupDescription_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 25).value = item("GroupDescription_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 26).value = item("GroupDescription_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 27).value = item("MaterialGroupCode")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 28).value = item("MaterialGroupDescription_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 29).value = item("MaterialGroupDescription_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 30).value = item("MaterialGroupDescription_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 31).value = item("MaterialGroupDescription_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 32).value = item("ItemDescription_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 33).value = item("ItemDescription_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 34).value = item("ItemDescription_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 35).value = item("GTINCode")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 36).value = item("IsStockItem")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 37).value = item("Warehouse")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 38).value = item("ItemVariety_NL")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 39).value = item("ItemVariety_DE")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 40).value = item("ItemVariety_EN")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 41).value = item("ItemVariety_FR")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 42).value = item("PotSize")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 43).value = item("ItemPictureName")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 44).value = item("ItemPictureSysmodified")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 45).value = item("Content_Ltr")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 46).value = item("PlantPassportCode")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 47).value = item("Diameter")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 48).value = item("Length")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 49).value = item("Width")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 50).value = item("Height")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 51).value = item("Depth")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 52).value = item("Opening")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 53).value = item("IsOffer")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 54).value = item("ShowOnWebsite")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 55).value = item("Sysmodified")
        Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 56).value = item("SalesOrderSize")
        
        
        
        k = 0
        
        For Each tag In item("Tags")
        
            For Each eigenschaft In tag("Values")
            
            Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 60 + k).value = tag("Code")
                Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 61 + k).value = eigenschaft("Description_DE")
                Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 62 + k).value = eigenschaft("Description_NL")
                Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 63 + k).value = eigenschaft("Description_EN")
                Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 64 + k).value = eigenschaft("Description_FR")
                'Worksheets("daten-api").Cells(i, 61 + k).value = tag("Values")(1)("Description_DE")
                k = k + 5
                
            Next
        
        Next tag
           
        i = i + 1
Next item
  
End Sub
```